# c++ Sorting a vector based on values of other vector, or what's faster?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, vector, std-pair

There are a couple of other posts about sorting a vector A based on values in another vector B. Most of the other answers tell to create a struct or a class to combine the values into one object and use std::sort.

Though I'm curious about the performance of such solutions as I need to optimize code which implements bubble sort to sort these two vectors. I'm thinking to use a `vector<pair<int,int>>`  and sort that.

I'm working on a blob-tracking application (image analysis) where I try to match previously tracked blobs against newly detected blobs in video frames where I check each of the frames against a couple of previously tracked frames and of course the blobs I found in previous frames.  I'm doing this at 60 times per second (speed of my webcam).

Any advice on optimizing this is appreciated.  The code I'm trying to optimize can be shown here:

http://code.google.com/p/projectknave/source/browse/trunk/knaveAddons/ofxBlobTracker/ofCvBlobTracker.cpp?spec=svn313&r=313

**important: I forgot to mention that the size of the vectors will never be bigger than 5, and mostly have only 3 items in it and will be unsorted (maybe I could even hardcode it for 3 items?)**

Thanks

Comment: "optimize code which implements bubble sort" ... why not optimize it into a quicksort?

Comment: shoosh, thanks! I'm not prejudiced about the solution, but curious what would be a good approch of doing this

Comment: or any other kind of sort, assuming the vectors are not already sorted

Comment: For such a small dataset to be sorted, look into shell sort.

Answer (score 3):

C++ provides lots of options for sorting, from the `std::sort` algorithm to sorted containers like `std::map` and `std::set`. You should always try to use these as your first solution, and only try things like "optimised bubble sorts" as  a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this a while ago. Also, I think you mean ordering a vector B in the same way as the 
sorted values of A.

`Index` contains the sorting order of `data`.

```
/** Sorts a vector and returns index of the sorted values
 * \param Index Contains the index of sorted values in the original vector
 * \param data The vector to be sorted
 */
template<class T>
void paired_sort(vector<unsigned int> & Index, const vector<T> & data)
{
    // A vector of a pair which will contain the sorted value and its index in the original array
    vector<pair<T,unsigned int>> IndexedPair;
    IndexedPair.resize(data.size());
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<IndexedPair.size();++i)
    {
        IndexedPair[i].first = data[i];
        IndexedPair[i].second = i;
    }
    sort(IndexedPair.begin(),IndexedPair.end());
    Index.resize(data.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < Index.size(); ++i) Index[i] = IndexedPair[i].second;
}
```

Comment: Yes this a bit what I mean but I'm also searching for a the -best- solution for this kind of thing; So actually I'm not stuck to these two vectors; any solution will be okay as long if it's FAST :) for this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob: I'm not a fan of making copies of each `T`, as this can be slow, and makes it unusable on uncopiable objects.  Why not use a `T*`?